# INNER JOIN com where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas :
permissoes_users

- id_user
- id_permissao

permissoes
 - id
 - permissao

Tenho uma variavel da sessao onde tenho o id di user , preciso fazer uma busca na tabela pelo id e as que tiverem o id do usuario exibir o nome da permissao...
Como posso fazer?

Erro testando a primeira resposta:

```
Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51
```

Código completo :

```
<body>
<?php
$id_user = $_GET['id_user']; 
function user_info_gamb ($id_user) {
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
      return mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
}
$nome = user_info_gamb($id_user);
//$permissao_pg = 1; include('funcoes/restringirpg.php'); 
?>
<div id="topo">
<?php  echo "Bem - Vindo  " . $nome["nome"]; include('funcoes/menu.php');?>
</div>

<div id="conteudo">
<table class="table-auto table-striped text-center" width="auto" border="0" align="center" >
  <tr>
    <td><strong>PERMISSÕES</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <?php
  function permissao_info ($id_permissao) {
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM permissoes WHERE id = '$id_permissao'");
      return mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
  }
    $aux = 0;

      $permissoes = mysql_query(" SELECT PU.ID_USER, P.PERMISSAO FROM PERMISSOES_USERS PU INNER JOIN PERMISSOES P ON PU.ID_PERMISSAO = P.ID ");
        for ($i=0; $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($permissoes); $i++){$permissao = $row["permissao"];

            echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$permissao</td>
            </tr>
            ";

        }

  ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente isso

```
SELECT PU.ID_USER, P.PERMISSAO FROM PERMISSOES_USERS PU
INNER JOIN PERMISSOES P ON PU.ID_PERMISSAO = P.ID
WHERE PU.ID_USER = 1
```

Quanto ao erro

> Notice: Undefined index: permissao in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DEV WEB/projetoFinalBD/permissao.php on line 51

é porque aqui `$permissao = $row["permissao"]` estás tentando acessar a coluna `permissao` mas o nome da coluna é `PERMISSAO` (com letras maiúsculas).

Comment: deu errado ....

Comment: Dizer "deu errado" não é o bastante né. O que deu errado?

Comment: Acabei de adicionar a mensagem de erro na pergunta